# Newest Ubuntu on weak Asus

Tags: asus

I have some question.
This would be my first time with Ubuntu,I bought some cheap notebook Asus K50C-SX002. Can I use newest Ubuntu on that notebook without any problems? Maybe my notebook is too weak for that newest release of Ubuntu? Can you help me?
Peter.

Comment: What are *exactly* the specs, it surely can run Ubuntu though not as you would want it to.., there are other official derivatives such as Lubuntu and Xubuntu for weaker Computers.

Comment: New $400-something(US$) Asus EeePC with 1.8 GHz Atom CPU, 2GB RAM runs 11.10 just as well as my older but better spec'd 2.00 Ghz Core 2 Duo w/ 4GB RAM. For what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Dual core processors of any type should play well with Ubuntu 11.10 and beyond. However, if your Atom is a single-core, (which I don't thinks so because you said $400), it should still be able to run Unity 2D if Unity 3D is too heavy or laggy. Try a live CD, or live USB, watch performance and if you are confortable, go Ubuntu.

If not, faster experiences may be found on Xubuntu or Lubuntu, as said by @Uri Herrera.

If you let us know the exact model of your ASUS, (or maybe somethings wrong since google gives me a Celeron laptop), we could be able to tell you how much performance could you get. Good luck! ;)